# MouseDown Outside Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to automatize a clicking task on several buttons on a browser that changes coordinates (without using Macro recorders & other things)

My code so far in Visual Basic:

```
Class Form1
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        TextBox1.Text = MousePosition.X
        TextBox2.Text = MousePosition.Y
    End Sub
    Private Sub Control_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
        Timer1.Stop()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The Problem: Timer doesn't stop when I click outside the Form, after researching I found 2 hits but I have no idea how to implement them

Hit 1: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171545%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
(Example how to implement?)

Hit 2: To set up a low level mouse hook (No idea how)

Thanks

Comment: @MADLeo then put this additional information as an [edit] to your question. I removed irrelevant comments - please keep them civil.

Comment: MouseCapture will NOT benefit you, it wont benefit you because you are trying to detect mouse clicks OUTSIDE your form.